# Google Spreadsheet does not return data to Google Chart if user is not logged in

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, google-visualization, google-sheets, google-drive-api

[My charts](http://sgratrace.appspot.com/) work perfectly on Chrome and Firefox but breaks on IE10. The IE10 console reports the following error:

> SEC7112: Script from https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key%3D0ArgBv2Jut0VxdERtWEU4UE5BbFd2TnZzVW8yTlB5eFE%26headers%3D1%26gid%3D0%26pub%3D1%26tq%3Dselect%2BL,%2BA,%2BH,%2BB,%2BI,%2BC,%2BF,%2BE,%2BG%2Bwhere%2BJ%2B%253D%2B... **DreqId:0 was blocked due to mime type mismatch** 
>   sgratrace.appspot.com

Code for querying the spreadsheet:

```
Rats.Viz.GraduateEmploymentSurvey.Overview.query = function() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
        Rats.Viz.GraduateEmploymentSurvey.Overview.dataSourceUrl);

    // Group by IHL and Post NS status
    // Pivot by year
    query.setQuery("select H, sum(D), sum(E) group by H pivot A " +
        "label sum(D) '', sum(E) '' " +
        "format sum(D) '$#,###', sum(E) '##.#%' ");

    query.send(Rats.Viz.GraduateEmploymentSurvey.Overview.dashboard);
};
```

Full code here: https://github.com/seahrh/sgratrace/blob/master/war/js/rats.js

Unfortunately IE10 also refuses to play well with [Google API Playground](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets) so I can't check whether the documentation code examples work on IE10.

EDIT: The charts work on IE9 (build 9.0.8112.16421) but not IE10 (build 10.0.9200.16635).

I think probably Chart Tools is returning a javascript file without the javascript MIME type and this is causing IE a great deal of discomfort: [IE9 script response blocked due to mime type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986772/ie9-script-response-blocked-due-to-mime-type-mismatch)

**EDIT2**

Found more info on this issue in this [forum thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-visualization-api/o2Okyr5vK3E/Vj0oeX7--ZAJ). The error seems to arise from **Google Spreadsheet** instead of Visualization API. IE and Chrome force user to login before Google spreadsheet returns data to chart. See ticket #1281 lodged with Visualization API: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1281

Comment: I made a simple test case using your data source URL and query, and it works fine in IE 8-11: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/x2Hsg/.  Try reducing your code to the simplest form that doesn't work, and debug that.

Comment: @asgallant Thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately the fiddle that you shared with me doesn't work on my IE. The console reports the same error SEC7112: something was blocked due to mime type mismatch. There was also a pop-up that says request timed out. > My IE build number is 10.0.9200.16635 and Update Versions as at 10.0.7 (KB2846071). I even tried lowering the security setting to Medium but that didn't work. I'm pulling my hair out here because everything works on Chrome, FF and Opera.

Comment: Hmmm...my simplified example works fine for me, but when using your code it breaks.  I shall have to think on this some more.

Comment: Anyone interested in this issue please star #1281 over at google's bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1281

Comment: @asgallant Thank you for the fiddle. However when I try it on IE10 I get the same error "...blocked due to mime type mismatch". In IE9 (and other browsers) it works fine. I've been Googling like crazy for a workaround without any success.

Comment: @oneleggedmule - If you append the question with: "...if so, how do you get around it without switching datasource?" I will start a bounty on the question. Perhaps also worth adding the fiddle-link. I'd be extremely happy for a workaround on this problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem with IE 11 and the Google Sheets API. I get a `for each` error